# python2.7 - store boolean values as individual bits when writing to disk

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing code that converts integers into padded 8-bit strings. I would then like to write those strings to a binary file. I am having problems figuring out the proper `dtype` to be used with the numpy array that I am currently using.

In the following code when I have `bin_data` variable set up with `dtype=np.int8` the output is:

```
$ python bool_dtype.py 
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 1, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
16
```

When `bin_data` is set as `dtype=np.bool_` the output is always true as shown below:

```
$ python bool_dtype.py 
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 1, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 1, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 0, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 1, bool(a[j]) = True
a[j] = 1, bool(a[j]) = True
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
16
```

When I look at the xxd dump of the data when using the `dtype=np.int8` I see an expected byte being used to represent each bit (1,0) IE 00000001 or 00000000. Using `dtype=np.bool_` leads to the same problem.

## So the two main questions I have are

1. Why is bool always reading as True when reading an array element
2. How can I more efficiently store the data when I write it to the file such that a single bit is **not** stored as a byte but instead just concatenated onto the previous element?

Here is the code in question, Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import numpy as np
import os

# x = np.zeros(200,dtype=np.bool_)
# for i in range(0,len(x)):
#     if i%2 != 1:
#         x[i] = 1

data_size = 2
data = np.random.randint(0,9,data_size)
tx=''
for i in range(0,data_size):
    tx += chr(data[i])
data = tx
a = np.zeros(8,dtype=np.int8)
bin_data = np.zeros(len(data)*8,dtype=np.bool_)

# each i is a character byte in data string
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    # formats data in 8bit binary without the 0b prefix
    a = format(ord(data[i]),'b').zfill(8)
    for j in range(0,len(a)):
        bin_data[i*len(a) + j] = a[j]
        print("a[j] = {}, bool(a[j]) = {}").format(a[j], bool(a[j]))

print bin_data[1:10]
print len(bin_data)

path = os.getcwd()
path = path + '/bool_data.bin'
data_file = open(path, "wb")
data_file.write(bin_data)
data_file.close()
```

### edit:

What I expect to see when using `dtype=np.bool_`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros(2,dtype=np.bool_)
>>> a
array([False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a[1] = 1
>>> a
array([False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The reason that bool is always returning true is that a[j] is a nonempty **string**. You need to cast a[j] to an int before testing with bool (and also before assigning it as an entry to a numpy bool array).
2. You can just call numpy.packbits to compress your boolean array into a uint8 array, (it pads for you if needed) and then call numpy.unpackbits to reverse the operation.

**Edit:**
If your boolean array has a length that isn't a multiple of 8, after packing and unpacking your array will be zero-padded to make the length a multiple of 8. In this case, you have two options:

1. If you can safely truncate your data to have a number of bits that is divisible by 8, then do so. Something like: `data=data[:8*(len(data)/8)]`
2. If you can't afford to truncate, then you are going to record the number of meaningful bits somehow. I suggest making the first byte of your  packed data equal to the number of meaningful bits mod 8. This will add only one byte of memory overhead, and not much compute time. Something like:

## Packing

```
bool_data = np.array([True, True, True])
nbits = len(bool_data)
rem = nbits % 8
nbytes = nbits/8
if rem: nbytes += 1
data = np.empty(1+nbytes, dtype=np.uint8)
data[0] = rem
data[1:] = np.packbits(bool_data)
```

## Unpacking

```
rem = data[0]
bool_data = np.unpackbits(data[1:])
if rem:
  bool_data = bool_data[:-(8-rem)]
```

Comment: Follow up question: If I have an amount of bits that is not a multiple of 8 after packing and unpacking I do not have the same stream. Is there an elegant pythonic way of dealing with this or should I just manually calculate my overflow and chop it off each time?

(I'm passing data between modules via sockets so it will increase my overhead greatly if I need to pass what the erroneous amounts of data are and remove them for each transaction)

Comment: Great code example. Should the line in Packing,  "nbytes = nbits/8", be changed to "nbytes = nbits//8" ?